# Issue on Add to Cart in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using Magento `1.7` and getting an issue while do `AddToCart`. Its showing empty shopping cart but I am very surprised to see that after deleting session and cache in `var` directory, its working fine.

Please help me to sort out this issue. Thanks in advance. Hope you understand my point!

Comment: Try with the Caches disabled.
Do you have external cache tools (memcached, Varnish...?)

Comment: Tried with Caches disabled but not working for me. I don't have any external cache tools

Comment: Do you have any lead, like have you recently installed a community module or made any changed that could mess with the sessions?

Comment: No, but I had changed sever to cloud. Server company changed at their own.